# Access deep link information from Reminders API?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios9, deep-linking, eventkit, reminders

iOS 9 introduces a new reminders feature which allows you to deep link back to any app (including 3rd party apps which implement the [NSUserActivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUserActivity_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSUserActivity) API).

For example, if you launch Messages, tap a conversation, hold the home button, and say, "Remind me about this in 5 minutes," you will get a reminder with a Messages icon. Tapping on the Messages icon from within Reminders later on will take you directly to that conversation.

If I use the [EKReminder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKReminderClassRef/) API, I can get this reminder, but can I get any of this other information?

In other words, is there any way to:

- Know that this reminder has special metadata associated with it?
- Get the deep link associated with it?
- Get the icon of the app that will handle the deep link (just like the Reminders app does)?

---

From [Apple's iOS 9 page](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/):

> [image]
>
> ### "Remind me about this when I get in the car."
>
> Siri can remind you about things you’re looking at in your apps — like Safari, Mail, and Notes — and want to follow up on later. If you’re halfway through an email, you can say “Remind me about this tonight.” Or if you’re looking at a place in Maps you want to stop at later, you can ask for a reminder when you get to your car.